# Why doesn't .htaccess have any effect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debian

I have a .htaccess file in a directory, but it has no effect (no matter what I put in it).

My apache2.conf file contains

```
AccessFileName .htaccess

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

It already said `AccessFileName .htaccess` but I added the Directory tag myself, thus I'm not sure if it's correct.

Thanks for any advice and requests for more information.

My .htaccess content (for now)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule .* page.php?arg=$0
```

Comment: try putting some bogus stuff in .htaccess and accessing the dir it applies to - if you get a 500 when accessing the dir, you'll at least know your .htaccess is being parsed.  where are you placing it?

Comment: It's placed in the directory I'm accessing (In this case /var/www/avesta/). I have already placed lots of bogus in the .htaccess file. I know it's not being parsed :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're on Debian, according to your tags.  The default site, at least on Lenny in its default configuration of apache2, is defined in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.  This default has `AllowOverride None` in the section for the /var/www directory.  So, that could be overriding your apache2.conf.

Of course, you would need to ensure that the site is enabled.  If /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default exists and is a symlink pointing to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default, then the site is enabled.  The canonical way to enable such a site is, as root, `a2ensite 000-default`.

Finally, realize that if you have access to the main configuration, for performance reasons, you should configure your site using the main configuration (or the site configurations in /etc/apache2/sites-available) rather than in .htaccess.  See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I changed `AllowOverride` to All in 000-default. Now I'm getting an Internal Server Error even without any rewrite arguments. Any ideas? (.htaccess now only contains `Options +FollowSymlinks` and  `RewriteEngine on`)

Comment: There are several reasons that could happen.  Do you have same error if you delete .htaccess altogether?  Also, note that you need to reload Apache to read the new config.  I usually just restart: as root, /etc/init.d/apache2 restart.  But, using "reload" rather than "restart" is also supposed to work.

Comment: I did restart apache, yes. It works with an empty .htaccess file, but not as soon as I add `RewriteEnging on`

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?  There would be a symlink /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load.  If not, as root, a2enmod rewrite.