# ModRewrite doesn't rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess file with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^heh$ ok
```

But when I go to `http://XXXXX/heh`, it is still on `http://XXXXX/heh`, but not on `http://XXXXX/ok`. What problem do I have?

P.S. This helped: [Why doesn't .htaccess have any effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111682/why-doesnt-htaccess-have-any-effect). I hate Apache.

Comment: Try putting some random characters in that file and see what happens ...

Comment: .htaccess isn't parsed at all! How to fix that?

Comment: You probably need to adjust `AllowOverride` in your `httpd.conf` or virtual host conf.

Comment: @lanzz, where should I add this? I tried to add it to httpd.conf but it doesn't work. Then I tried to use `<Directory ...>` tag, but it also doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It's should do the job...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ok$ heh [L]
```

Comment: This doesn't help too. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Please Checkout:
    `RedirectMatch 301 /heh/(.*) /ok/$1`