# .htaccess rewrite not working on new server

Tags: .htaccess

I have just transferred a website over to a new server and now the .htaccess file redirects do not seem to be working. Please see below for an example:

```
# .htaccess

#Rewrite rules
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /weddings/

RewriteRule ^facilities facilities.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^catering catering.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+) ../general/gallery.php?gal=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^gallery ../general/gallery.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^location ../general/location.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^floor_plans ../general/floor_plans.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^testimonials ../general/testimonials.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^prices ../general/prices.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^parking ../general/parking.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^accommodation ../general/accommodation.php [NC]
```

Any suggestions to why this could be?

Thanks

Comment: make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on httpd.conf

Comment: Hi Timus, where will I find https.conf?

Comment: `httpd.conf`, not `https.conf`. In Debian it is `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Comment: How do you know it is not working? What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: I have done a file search and this file does not seem to exist?

Comment: I have uploaded the website to: http://195.8.196.242/~binghamh/

Comment: If you click on weddings then facilities a broken link is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled `.htaccess`. Somewhere in your Apache config, you should have

```
AllowOverride All
```

Also make sure mod_rewrite is installed and enabled. In Debian, symlink `/etc/apache2/mod-enabled/rewrite.load` should point to `../mods_available/rewrite.load`. Otherwise see [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869092/2157640).

Comment: Hi Palec,I am unable to find a Apache config file?

Comment: @user2695578 I assume you are using Linux. It should be in `/etc`, probably `/etc/apache2`. What distro do you use?

Comment: The website and admin area was bespokely made by someone else (who I do not know) there is no etc folder I have tried doing a search file too

Comment: @user2695578 I did not speak about DocumentRoot. `/etc` is filesystem path, `etc` directory in the server filesystem root.

Comment: Sorry Palec I have now found the etc folder but there the file isn't in there. Do you think this is something I should take up with my host?

Comment: @user2695578 What file is not there? The `/etc/apache2` directory? If you cannot change the server config, you need to solve the problem with somebody who can. If you want to be sure that `.htaccess` is completely disabled, you can try creating a parse error in your `.htaccess`. If you do not get 500 error at each page in the same directory, then `.htaccess` is disabled.

Comment: The httpd.conf is not there nor the apache2 directory. I have made a mistake in the .htaccess file and I do not get a 500 error

Comment: @user2695578 See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4111682/2157640 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15956131/2157640. As I wrote, you have to contact someone who can help you with server configuration. `.htaccess` is just a part of it and in your case it is obviously disabled.

Comment: @user2695578 Anyway, I think my answer deserves to be accepted. I pointed you to the right direction, explicitly answered your question (“Any suggestions on why this could be?”) and finally we tracked down the problem. Now it is up to your host. I believe that after you enable `.htaccess`, your site will work OK.